# Reshuffle at the kitchen

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

what is the word to use when I want to say that I rearranged possessions in my room: furniture and other stuff?

My question is about expediency of using the word "reshuffle" , can I use it in this context?

and what is the correct formulation? Should I say "I reshuffled the the possession"?  or should I say " I did/made a reshuffle "?

Comment: As another note, I would not say *reshuffle* unless you've *shuffled* them once already. If it's the first time moving things around after having originally placed them, then it would just be *shuffle*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can, but it seems deliberately odd.

Re-shuffle is normally used in a political context, when the Prime Minister wants to change ministers, we say she "reshuffles her cabinet".  You can use "reshuffle", but in doing so you personify your furniture as politicians. This is probably not the effect you intend.

So the normal word to use is "rearrange".  You can "I rearranged my furniture/possessions/living-room." You could even say "I made a big rearrangement of my whole home"